# declare and initialize variable in XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

"Artproof" variable is true.
i want to change color of text if variable is true

```
<xsl:variable name="ArtProof" select="'True'"/>     

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$ArtProof = 'True'">
        <xsl:variable name="color_of_artproof" select="'green'"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="color_of_artproof" select="'red'"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Set color condition is:

"color_of_artproof" variable is giving Null Value, and text is in black color.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is scoped to to its parent element. If you define a variable within a `xsl:when` instruction, then you cannot use it in another context.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="color_of_artproof">
    <xsl:when test="$ArtProof = 'True'">green</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:variable>
```